# Devise with ajax POST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I can't access `current_user` in my api controller when sending a `POST` request.
It says it is null.

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_default_format
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    private
        def set_default_format
            request.format = :json
        end
end

class Api::V1::PhotosController < ApiController
...
end
```

What am I doing wrong? I read a couple of posts on SO and the solutions do not work.

Comment: Quick question -- Did you forget `before_action :authenticate_user!`?

Comment: @31piy No, it is there, in the Api::V1::PhotosController, sorry I did not include it here.